# How can we prove what the shortest line between two points avoiding convex obstacles is? (visibility graphs)?

Tags: computational-geometry, shortest-path, convex-geometry

I came across the observation in russell & norvig's artificial intelligence book that the shortest path between two points while avoiding convex polygonal obstacles is a sequence of line segments between vertices of the polygonal obstacles.

This seems intuitive enough, but how do we prove this?

I have found several resources that seem to gloss over this:

1 and 2) [Previous stackexchange answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36335/what-is-the-proof-that-visibility-graphs-can-be-used-to-compute-the-shortest-pat), which says this problem is reducible to having lines as obstacles, but the [Ph.D. thesis it refers to](https://www.proquest.com/docview/302879719?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true) doesn't actually seem to provide a proof for this either, as there is no proof given for Corollary 5.1 on p. 112 (whereas the theorem it is a corollary to seems to have a very simple proof).

3. [Stanford geometric algorithms lecture notes](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-11-spring/notes/handout7.pdf) also gloss over this, no proof provided for lemma 2.
4. [Another paper I found](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0020019086900451) also says for the relevant Lemma 1 "we don't provide the simple proof [...]."

I can't tell if I'm just missing something obvious that most readers can just fill in the blanks with or not.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Triangle Inequality. For any path, that has a *vertex* outside the polygonal obstacle, you can create a shorter path.